How to avoid blank pages in iOS Edge when opening link in its own app
I am developing an Angular responsive app, and after doing some tests in iOS I found that, in every browser but Safari, opening a link associated with another app using window.open opens a blank tab before opening the default app, and leaves the blank tab in the browser. This causes a lot of blank pages in the user's browser.
This is a snippet of the component's template:
<span class="action-buttons">
  <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="link" (click)="openLink(link)" target="_blank">
    <mat-icon>arrow_right_alt</mat-icon>
  </button>
</span>

And this is the openLink method:
protected openLink(link: string): void {
  window.open(link, '_blank');
}

(I'm using window.open(link, '_blank') to avoid losing the current page in case a dedicated app is not available.)
Using the code above, opening a link to a site with a dedicated app (e.g. Reddit) works flawlessly in Android and using Safari in iOS, but using Chrome and Edge in iOS leaves a blank page behind.
